# Keycloak configuration with Kerberos

Tags: authentication, ldap, keycloak, kerberos, keycloak-services

I need to configure LDAP/Kerberos auth for keycloak.

First Error1#
Received kerberos token, but there is no  user storage provider that handles kerberos credentials.

Second Error2#
#true storeKey true useTicketCache false useKeyTab true doNotPrompt true                                                                              ticketCache is null isInitiator false KeyTab is /home/aykhan/keycloak-23.0.4/d                                                                             ata/keycloak.keytab  refreshKrb5Config is false principal is HTTP/KEYCLOAC-T01@                                                                             TESTNIKOIL.AZ tryFirstPass is false useFirstPass is false storePass is false clear                                                                             Pass is false
principal is HTTP/KEYCLOAC-T01@TESTNIKOIL.AZ
Will use keytab
Commit Succeeded

What did I make wrong?

Please could you tell me what I did wrong?